# Rails 4: order by attribute of has_many table, then join uniquely to that table, then group by that attribute

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have something like the following (obfuscated names and simplified from my work) in rails models:

```
Show < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :airings
end

Airing < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :viewers

  #a DateTime
  def start_time
    super
  end

end

Viewer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :ratings
end

Rating < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

I need to assign each Show a date by the start_time it first airs, and then get some data: the number of viewers for each show date in a month, the number of ratings for each show date in a month. I'd like to use the groupdate gem to group by date.

I've gotten this far:

```
scope  :by_start_time, -> {
    joins(
    "inner join airings st on shows.id = st.show_id",
    airings: {viewers: :ratings}
    ).where("st.id in (?)", 
        ShowTime.group("st.show_id"
        ).having("st.start_time = MIN(st.start_time)").select("st.id"
    )).select(
    "shows.*, st.start_time, st.start_time as show_start"
   ).distinct
```

Comment: Is speed an issue? It would probably be simpler, and easier to maintain, to either do this in multiple queries or bringing results into ruby and crunching the data then.

Comment: Yes it is to some extent.  I'd settle for this not being an N +  1 query for each day of the month though.